# How to split string with windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a code that creates a bulk folder for each file and drags the file into the corresponding folder, but I am trying to shorten (split) the string.

For example, convert

```
L2021-56378 Sample Documentation Form 
L2022-56378 Sample Documentation Form
L2023-56378 Sample Documentation Form
```

to just

```
L2021-56378
L2022-56378
L2023-56378
```

Below is my code:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  for /f %%e in ("%%~ni") do (
   ECHO %%e
   ECHO md "%%e" 2>nul&& ECHO move "%%~i" "%%e"
  )
 )
...
```

should do that - I'm assuming you want a directory named `L2021-56378` and to move the file to that directory.

The `ECHO` keywords are present to report the intended operations to the screen for verification. Remove them if the commands are correct to actually do the `md` and `move`.

See `for /?` from the prompt or many, many items on SO for documentation. The `for/f` uses default options `tokens=1` and `delims` includes <kbd>Space</kbd>

----- Applying this to your code,

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (


 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  for /f %%e in ("%%~ni") do (
   ECHO %%e
   ECHO md "%%e" 2>nul&& ECHO move "%%~i" "%%e"
  )
 )


)
```

works for me.

Comment: Sorry I should have elaborated more. Basically, I have a PDF file named "L2022-67845 Sample Documentation Form". I want the code to: create a folder named "L2022-67845" and then move "L2022-67845 Sample Documentation Form" to that folder. In other words, the folder "L2022-67845" contains the file  "L2022-67845 Sample Documentation Form".

Comment: Does this code do that? Remember that you need to remove the `echo` keywords to actually do the move and **Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Comment: It didn't, and I removed all the echo keywords. It just created an empty folder named "%~ni"

Comment: Thank you. The new code worked!